# Stripe.js checkout confirmation is not working

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Im trying to confirm stripe payment with `stripe.js` by updating the parent child state with something like `successPayment` to `true` , that way I could show the user a success toast, but my code is not working.

PD: I don't want user to be redirected to a '/success' or something, I want that all the events happend on the home page '/'

Components tree:

```
<PaymentSection> // successPayment state defined here
  <StripeCheckout handleSetSuccess={handleSetSuccess} />
  {
     success ? (<SuccessToast />) : (Pending payment!)
  }
</PaymentSection>
```

My code

````
// Initialize stripe promise
let stripePromise;
const getStripe = () => {
  if (!stripePromise) {
    stripePromise = loadStripe(import.meta.env.VITE_STRIPE_KEY);
  }
  return stripePromise;
};

// Create a checkout component
const StripeCheckout = ({ handleSetSuccess }) => {
  const item = {
    price: "price_1LzKZJKB9bDMUf725vIXQB7p",
    quantity: 1,
  };

  const checkoutOptions = {
    lineItems: [item],
    mode: "payment",
    successUrl: `${window.location.origin}`,
    cancelUrl: `${window.location.origin}`,
  };

  const redirectToCheckout = async () => {
    const stripe = await getStripe();
    await stripe.redirectToCheckout(checkoutOptions);

    // Here I want to handle the success case, if I got a successfull payment
    // I want to update my `successPayment` state to true, so I can show a success message on my page
    // PD: I don't want to redirect the user to another page, I want to stay on the same page because my app is a SPA
  };

  return (
    <div className="payment-button">
      <h3 onClick={redirectToCheckout} >
         Obtener <span style={{ fontWeight: 900 }}>50 avatares</span>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StripeCheckout;```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's not recommended to use `redirectedToCheckout` in this way, which has been deprecated for some time and has [significant limitations](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client). Instead, you should either use a [client-server Checkout integration](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=checkout) (creating Checkout sessions on your server), or consider redirecting users to [Payment Links](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links).

That said, you can handle this in your current integration. You need to be able to distinguish success from failure in your redirect URLs, which are currently identical. Adding something like a query parameter `?success=true` on the `successUrl` would allow you to inspect that following direction and apply the logic in your code to display what you like. You can also [include the session id in the success URL](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page) to allow you to retrieve payment & customer information via your server.

Note that you should be careful to only [fulfill orders](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#create-event-handler) following explicit confirmation of success, either using the `checkout.session.completed` webhook or by retrieving the session by `id` and inspecting the status. Do not assume arrival at a "success URL" is reliable (a customer could manipulate the page URL manually).